# Pandas: Calculate the difference between two Datetime columns from different timezones

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I have two different time series. One is a series of timestamps in ms-format from the CET timezone delivered as strings. The other are unix-timestamps in s-format in the UTC timezone.

Each of them is in a column in a larger dataframe, none of them is a DatetimeIndex and should not be one.

I need to convert the CET time to UTC and then calculate the difference between both columns and I'm lost between the Datetime functionalities of Python and Pandas, and the variety of different datatypes.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz

germany = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')

D1 = ["2016-08-22 00:23:58.254","2016-08-22 00:23:58.254",
      "2016-08-22 00:23:58.254","2016-08-22 00:40:33.260",
      "2016-08-22 00:40:33.260","2016-08-22 00:40:33.260"]

D2 = [1470031195, 1470031195, 1470031195, 1471772027, 1471765890, 1471765890]

S1 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(D1))
S2 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(D2),unit='s')
```

### First problem

is with the use of `tz_localize`. I need the program to understand, that the data in `S1` is not in UTC, but in CET. However using `tz_localize` like this seems to interpret the given datetime as CET assuming it's UTC to begin with:

```
F1 = S1.apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize(germany)).to_frame()
```

Trying `tz_convert` always throws something like:

> TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex

### Second problem

is that even with both of them having the same format I'm stuck because I can't calculate the difference between the two columns now:

```
F1 = S1.apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize(germany)).to_frame()
F1.columns = ["CET"]
F2 = S2.apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize('UTC')).to_frame()
F2.columns = ["UTC"]
FF = pd.merge(F1,F2,left_index=True,right_index=True)
FF.CET-FF.UTC
```

> ValueError: Incompatbile tz's on datetime subtraction ops

I need a way to do these calculation with tz-aware datetime objects that are no DatetimeIndex objects.

**Alternatively** I need a way to make my CET-column to just look like this:

```
2016-08-21 22:23:58.254
2016-08-21 22:23:58.254
2016-08-21 22:23:58.254
2016-08-21 22:40:33.260
2016-08-21 22:40:33.260
2016-08-21 22:40:33.260
```

That is, I don't need my datetime to be tz-aware, I just want to convert it automatically by adding/subtracting the necessary amount of time with an awareness for daylight saving times.

If it weren't for DST I could just do a simple subtraction on two integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert the CET timestamps to datetime and specify the timezone:

```
S1 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(D1))
T1_cet = pd.DatetimeIndex(S1).tz_localize('Europe/Berlin')
```

Then convert the UTC timestamps to datetime and specify the timezone to avoid confusion:

```
S2 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(D2), unit='s')
T2_utc = pd.DatetimeIndex(S1).tz_localize('UTC')
```

Now convert the CET timestamps to UTC:

```
T1_utc = T1_cet.tz_convert('UTC')
```

And finally calculate the difference between the timestamps:

```
diff = pd.Series(T1_utc) - pd.Series(T2_utc)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. I thought I couldn't use a DatetimeIndex.